# laravel, Normal error Logged, but only One error with white screen

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, eloquent

I'm using laravel 5.4 withe laravel-datatables plugin

I have no problem with debugger plugin and the normal larval log error, but for some reason, one of the Bug not show at all and laravel display white page with no error :(

I believe the code related to my Eloquent relation ship problem the follow code product white page error

```
return Datatables::of(InvoiceProduct::where('purchasing_order_id', 1))->make(true);
```

The above error only happen if the database purchasing_orders is Not Empty.

I also using DB to try get the same result as follow without and Error

```
return Datatables::of(DB::select('select * from invoice_products where purchasing_order_id = ' . $id))->make(true);
```

I really need to see what is the Error so I can fix it :(

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem with my code, but still don't know why 500 error is not log in storage/log, still don't know why white page, and still don't know how to fix it.

The problem is when I remove invoice_product in protect $with array, the error gone.

Here is the code that I edit.

```
//protected $with = ['invoice_products', 'customer', 'currency', 'company'];
//Comment out above line, the below line is working
protected $with = ['customer', 'currency', 'company'];
```

I believe that my relationship is wrong but can't find the problem,

Here is my code for "purchasing_orders model" Eloquent model, which have many "invoice_products"

```
class PurchasingOrder extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'purchasing_orders';
    protected $fillable = [
        'po_number', 'po_date',
        'invoice_reference', 'customer_id', 'customer_po_number', 'agent',
        'estimate_shipping_date', 'estimate_arrival_date', 'estimate_loading_date',
        'ship_to','to_user_name',
        'term', 'po_remark', 'worksheet_remark',
        'company_id','currency_id',
        'total_amount', 'total_quantity','total_net_weight','total_gross_weight','total_packed_cu_metric','total_pallets',
    ];

//Json come with product_unit and supplier that associated with prdocut
//protected $with = ['invoice_products', 'customer', 'currency', 'company'];
protected $with = ['customer', 'currency', 'company'];

 /**
 * Get the invoice_product of invoice.
 */
 //One invoice has many invoice_product
public function invoice_products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\InvoiceProduct');
}
 /**
 * Get the customer of invoice.
 */
 //One invoice has only one customer
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer', 'customer_id');
}
 /**
 * Get the currency of invoice.
 */
 //One invoice has only one currency
public function currency()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Currency', 'currency_id');
}
 /**
 * Get the company of invoice.
 */
 //One invoice has only one company
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'company_id');
}
```

And here is my code from "invoice_products" Eloquent model (belong to purchasing_order Eloquent model)

```
    class InvoiceProduct extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'invoice_products';
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id', 'customer_product_id','name', 'brand', 'packing',
        'gross_weight', 'net_weight','net_weight_packing',
        'product_unit_id', 'packed_cu_metric',
        'quantity','price','amount','pallets',
        'invoice_id', 'purchasing_order_id','container_id',
    ];

//Json come with InvocieProduct add PurchasingOrder
protected $with = ['purchasing_order', 'product', 'customer_product', 'container'];


public function purchasing_order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\PurchasingOrder', 'purchasing_order_id');
}

public function container()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Container');
}
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id');
}
public function customer_product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CustomerProduct', 'customer_product_id');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are using the query builder, this does not standard fetch the result, you will need to chain your call with a `->get()`

```
return Datatables::of(InvoiceProduct::where('purchasing_order_id', 1)->get())->make(true);
```

This will not only create the query but also execute it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I still got the same error with or without ->get().

At first when when InvoiceProducts table is empty is working fine, but after I add some record, Chrome developer tool return 500 error, but nothing in Laravel Debuggar also when I try to refresh after error, now the white page appear

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is looking at your error log file. Open `storage/logs` directory and you will find the reason of 500 error. It might be for example invalid column name, not imported model or may other reasons.

Comment: That the thing, I can't find anything in storage/logs :(

One more note when I remove "invoice_products" from "protected $with", in purchasing_order model, the code start working again 

    //Json come with invoice_products, customer and currency
    //protected $with = ['invoice_products', 'customer', 'currency', 'company'];
    protected $with = ['customer', 'currency', 'company'];

Comment: So if in developer tools in Chrome you see error 500, you should see there also the response with the reason what's wrong, right?

Comment: Nabialek

It only said that server response 500 error without detail